# django-allauth: Letting users disconnect social networks

Tags: django, django-allauth

The [django-allauth docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) claim to support a workflow that lets a user disconnect from a social network, and they even cover what signal is emitted when a user successfully disconnects an account.

But the documentation does not state how to initiate a disconnect. When I list all URLs in my allauth project, none of them reference disconnection.

Is there a form or URL or other mechanism to use for account disconnection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like there is a view for managing (adding/removing) your e-mail addresses (`/accounts/email/`), there is a view for managing (connecting/disconnecting) your social accounts (`/accounts/social/connections/`). There is no separate view for disconnecting a single account.

Comment: Thanks so much! A bit more documentation on that would be helpful, thanks.